# How to build freefilesync 5.23 for rhel 6.0 32 bit?

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets, 32-bit, rhel

Unable to build wxWidgets-2.9.5  and boost_1_54_0.

freefilesync MakeFile has these lines:

```
WX_CONFIG_BIN =$(HOME)/Desktop/wxWidgets-2.9.5/lib/release/bin/wx-config
CXXFLAGS  += -I$(HOME)/Desktop/boost_1_54_0
BOOST_LIB_DIR =$(HOME)/Desktop/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib
```

the problem is after building wxWidgets successfully this "/Desktop/wxWidgets-2.9.5/lib/release/bin/wx-config" file not available.

Comment: You should at least add extensive information about the errors you encounter.

Comment: I'm afraid that the only option is to build glib 2.15 as well...

Answer (score 0):

`wx-config` is not supposed to be in this directory, so this looks like a bug in freefilesync makefiles. If you just build wxWidgets in this directory, `wx-config` is found directly in it. If you also do `make install`, it is installed in the destination directory, `/usr/local/bin` by default but changeable with the configure `--prefix` option, as usual.